# how to create a keep-alive process in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm currently reading [Programming Erlang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193778553X)! , at the end of Chapter 13, we want to create a keep-alive process, 
the example likes:

```
on_exit(Pid, Fun) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
            Ref = monitor(process, Pid),
            receive
                {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Info} ->
                    Fun(Info)
            end
    end).
keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    register(Name, Pid = spawn(Fun)),
    on_exit(Pid, fun(_Why) -> keep_alive(Name, Fun) end).
```

but when between `register/2` and `on_exit/2` the process maybe exit, so the monitor will failed, I changed the `keep_alive/2` like this:

```
keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(Fun),
    register(Name, Pid),
    receive
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Info} ->
            keep_alive(Name, Fun)
end.
```

There also an bug, between `spawn_monitor/2` and `register/2`, the process maybe exit. How could this come to run successfully? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that you have a problem that needs solving. Monitor/2 will succeed even if your process exits after register/2. Monitor/2 will send a 'DOWN' message whose Info component will be noproc. Per the documentation:

> A 'DOWN' message will be sent to the monitoring process if Item dies, **if Item does not exist**, or if the connection is lost to the node which Item resides on. (see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2).

So, in your original code

1. register assocates Name to the Pid
2. Pid dies
3. on_exit is called and monitor/2 is executed
4. monitor immediately sends a 'DOWN' message which is received by the function spawned by on_exit
5. the Fun(Info) of the received statement is executed calling keep_alive/2

I think all is good.

Answer (score 2):

So why you did't want to use erlang supervisor behaviour? it's provides useful functions for creating and restarting keep-alive processes.

See here the example: http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html

Comment: I think the OP just wants to understand the exercise/example in the Programming Erlang book - I suspect he hasn't gotten to the OTP portion of that text, yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, if process exits before registration `register` will fail with `badarg`. The easiest way to get around that would be surrounding register with `try ... catch` and handle error in catch.

You can even leave catch empty, because even if registration failed, the `'DOWN'` message, will be sent.

On the other hand, I wouldn't do that in production system. If your worker fails so fast, it is very likely, that the problem is in its initialisation code and I would like to know, that it failed to register and stopped the system. Otherwise, it could fail and be respawned in an endless loop.