# why spawn spawn_link register may cause a race condition if we put them together in erlang?

Tags: process, concurrency, erlang

I am reading 《Programming Erlang》 by Joe Armstrong. He refers that if we put `spawn` `spawn_link` `register` together, it may cause a race condition, when discuss the code as follow:

```
keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    register(Name, Pid=spawn(Fun)),

    %% he says that process may die between these two code
    %% he also says that if two process use the same "Name" and call "keep_alive" 
    %% at the same time, it will cause the competition and make the process died 
    %% here(but I am not totally understand here).
    on_exit(Pid, fun(_why) -> keey_alive(Name, Fun) end).
```

And any solutions to solve this?

Comment: Look at this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25619920/258611

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a keep-alive process in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617769/how-to-create-a-keep-alive-process-in-erlang)